# Discord JS Allowing a user to a channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Here I am again needing some help!
So I'm coding a discord bot using JS, and I wanted to make a command that makes the user get temporary access to a channel, I know how to do that by adding roles, but my objective here it's to add only a user overwriting, not a entire role perm in the channel.
This is the code that I use for now, but I want to change it to a user perm overwrite

```
var role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Exclusive")
msg.member.roles.add(role)
setTimeout(() => {
msg.member.roles.remove(role)
})
```

Any help will be apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a permission overwrite for a user, simply use GuildChannel#updateOverwrite.

It supports both users and roles.

For example:

```js
var channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('desired-channel-id');
await channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
    VIEW_CHANNEL: true
});
```

This will grant the user access to the desired channel.

To deny the user the permissions, just turn `true` into `false`.

Hope this helps.